# Problema en instalación de CPUMiner en VPS

Tags: shell, centos, virtualización

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema con el **CPUMiner** en mi **VPS**, cuando lo voy a instalar todo bien, el **autogen.sh** funciona perfecta, y el **./configure** también, pero a la hora de realizar el comando **make** este me bota al final 2 errores:

> make[2]: [minerd-cpu-miner.o] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/root/cpuminer-multi'

Y no entiendo como solucionarlo. He intentado con todo, reinstalar el ***libcurl*** completo, osea **yum remove libcurl* libtool*** pero nada, he reinstalado el **gcc** también pero tampoco. Ya no tengo opciones, incluso reinstale el **M4** y el **automake**. Alguien que conozca el tema?

Comment: Hola Fulltron, creo que sacas de contexto la línea del error. ¿Cuándo falla? ¿Falta una librería? ¿Estás instalando el paquete de desarrollo de libcurl? Agrega un poco más de información para saber por qué falla el comando `make` en ese archivo.

Comment: Si, he instalado el libcurl completo incluyendo las dependencias y el A4 tambien, pero nada. Eso que puse alli es el error que me aparece

Comment: Verifica que librería de curl pide o incluye el directorio específico al llamar a `configure`.

Comment: Como realizo eso, ya que no me especializo tanto en eso

Comment: Bueno, creo que si no sabes usar `configure` tu pregunta es muy amplia. Busca una versión precompilada, tal vez exista. Y si no hay, revisa a conciencia los mensajes que aparecen cuando ejecutas `./configure` y ejecuta `./configure --help` para ver más opciones.